# How to force Django to use LEFT OUTER JOIN in query?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have two models: Person and Task.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    display_name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Task(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField()
    ...
```

**I want to get a list of ALL people along with amount of tasks (including 0).**

Initially, I wrote below query and it worked pretty well:

```
Person.objects.values('person_id', 'display_name').annotate(crt_task_amt=Count('task__id')).order_by('-crt_task_amt', 'display_name')
```

Later, I introduced a filter on is_deleted. **Then people with no tasks disappeared**:

```
Person.objects.filter(task__is_deleted=False).values('person_id', 'display_name').annotate(crt_task_amt=Count('task__id')).order_by('-crt_task_amt', 'display_name')
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
SELECT p.id, p.display_name, count(t.id) FROM dashboard_person p LEFT OUTER JOIN dashboard_task t ON (p.person_id=t.person_id AND t.is_deleted=0) GROUP BY t.person_id
```

Is there any way to achieve it without using raw SQL?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes django ORM decides to use INNER JOIN and sometimes LEFT OUTER JOIN. What is the logic behind, I haven't found yet. But I have tested some cases which get me idea behind.

Starting case (I am using django 1.8.1):

```
class Parent(...)
    ...

class Child(...):
    parent = ForeignKey(Parent)
    status = CharField()
    name   = CharField()
    ...

qs = Parent.object.all()
```

### Task 1: for each parent record count how many child records contains

This should work:

```
qs = qs.annotate(child_count_all=Count("child"))
```

Looking into `qs.query` - you can see that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is used, what is **correct**.

but if I do it with SUM + CASE-WHEN:

```
qs = qs.annotate(
        child_count=Sum(Case(default=1), output_field=IntegerField())
        )
```

Looking into `qs.query` - you can see that this time `INNER JOIN` is used, what will filter out all parent records which don't contain any child records, producing **wrong results**.

The workaround for this is something like:

```
qs = qs.annotate(
        child_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(child__id=None, then=0),
                default=1,
                output_field=IntegerField())
            ))
```

This time `qs.query` showed using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` producing **correct** results.

### Task 2: count how many active child records contains

Active child records are detected with status<>'INA'. Based on previous solution I tried following:

```
qs = qs.annotate(
        child_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(child__id=None, then=0),
                When(child__status='INA', then=0),
                default=1,
                output_field=IntegerField())
            ))
```

but again, the `qs.query` shows that `INNER JOIN` is being used, thus producing **wrong results** (for my case).

The workaround/solution is using two or-ed Q objects:

```
qs = qs.annotate(
        child_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(Q(child__id=None) | Q(child__status="INA"), then=0),
                default=1,
                output_field=IntegerField())
            ))
```

Again, `qs.query` used `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, yielding **correct** results.

### Task 3: same as 2 but count only records which have name filled

This works:

```
qs = qs.annotate(
        child_with_name_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(Q(child__id=None) | Q(child__status="INA"), then=0),
                When(child__name__isnull=False, then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField())
            ))
```

### Conclusion

Can not tell for sure why is sometimes used inner and sometimes left join, so my way how to deal with it was to test various combinations by inspecting qs.query until I found proper result. Other way is by using `qs.raw/join/extra` and other more native and advanced django ORM/SQL combinations.

Comment: Thanks Robert for looking into this. I ended up using `qs.raw` to solve the problem. SUM + CASE-WHEN could be the django way to go. But due to its unpredictable result, it's not an ideal solution. But good to know. Hope this will be fixed in the future release.

Answer (score 0):

```
q = Task.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).values('person__id').annotate(crt_task_amt=Count('id')).order_by('-crt_task_amt', 'person__display_name')

q[0].person_id  # gives person_id
q[0].display_name #gives person name
q[0].crt_task_amt # gives count of task of first person
```

**UPDATE:**

Hope this works.

```
Task.objects.filter(is_deleted=False, person__isnull = True).values('person__id').annotate(crt_task_amt=Count('id')).order_by('-crt_task_amt', 'person__display_name')
```

This can be done easily using joins, but you need to use little bit of raw SQL for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it has the same problem as my second query -- **People with no tasks disappear.**  That is also why I started the query with Person.objects. I want to get all people regardless of amount of tasks